# How compare 2 string arrays with duplicate records

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 string arrays for example

```
string[] a = {"The", "Big", "Ant", "The"};
string[] b = {"Big", "Ant", "Ran" };
```

Here I am comparing two `string[]` (`a` may contains duplicate elements as well). How to get not matched elements while comparing a and b in b(with duplicates as well). In *Linq* `Except` i am not getting *duplicate* records. I need to get *duplicates* as well.

```
b = a.Except(b).ToArray();
```

**Expected** result is (`"The"` doesn't appear in `b` and `"Run"` is not in `a`)

```
{"The", "The", "Ran"}
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: You can use, **var res = a.Where(x => !b.Contains(x)).ToArray();**

Comment: expected result would be var result = {"The", "The", "Ran"};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use,

```
var res = a.Where(x => !b.Contains(x)).ToArray();
```

**UPDATE**

```
List<string> res = a.ToList();
for(int i=0; i<b.Length; i++) {
   if (a.Contains(b[i]))
       res.Remove(b[i]);
    else
       res.Add(b[i]);
}
```

> res => **{"The","The","Ran"}**

Comment: I'd only add that if `b` can be a big array it might be worth creating a `HashSet` out of it so the line above would be an `O(n)` instead of `O(n^2)` operation

Comment: @Furkan Öztürk This linq expression will not include value`"Ran"` into result. @new_learner exprects the next result: `var result = {"The", "The", "Ran"};`.

Answer (score 1):

We can add two `Where` conditions and then just `Concat` two arrays:

```
string[] a = { "The", "Big", "Ant", "The" };
string[] b = { "Big", "Ant", "Ran" };

var res = a.Where(x => !b.Contains(x))
            .Concat(b.Where(b1 => !a.Contains(b1)));
```